# Delphi XE2 Fatal Error раздела implementation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

Перенес свое приложение с 7-ки в XE2. Перенес успешно, но возникла проблема. Компилятор периодически ругается на раздел "implementation" и выдает :

> [DCC Fatal Error] U_checklist.pas(348): F2084 Internal Error: AV076C4237-W00000000-1

Перезагрузка среды помогает, но порядком раздражает, т.к. такое повторяется достаточно часто.
Подскажите что делаю не так?
Вот например первые строки 1го из модулей где выдает ошибку:

```
unit U_checklist;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, sButton, sListBox, sCheckListBox, ExtCtrls, sPanel;

type
  TF_checklist = class(TForm)
    sPanel1: TsPanel;
    sPanel2: TsPanel;
    sCheckListBox1: TsCheckListBox;
    sButton1: TsButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sCheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sCheckListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sCheckListBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  end;

var
  F_checklist: TF_checklist;

implementation

uses Types, U_main, Math, U_DM;

{$R *.dfm}
```

Comment: Полагаю, тут ничего не поможет
У меня так же в XE2 периодами возникает похожая ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего необходимо перекомпилировать все сторонние компоненты в новой среде так как подключаются старые dcu файлы проекта скомпилированные в D7.
Очистите проект с помощью **Clean**. (возможно вообще проект на заведется после этого)) )

[image]

Comment: А лучше вручную удалить все dcu-шки из папки с проектом (кроме сторонних, конечно).

Comment: Спасибо, всё помогло. Проект завелся. Fatal Error пока не появлялся.

Comment: К сожалению, эти меры помогли не полностью. Какие еще шаги можно предпринять?

Comment: что на этот раз?

Comment: Да все та же ошибка в том же месте, но уже другого модуля. DCU-шки все чистил.

Comment: Может попробовать переустановить XE2?

Comment: Попробую переустановить, в последнем моем вопросе нет возможности добавлять комментарии, там локальная проблема решена.

Comment: ооо кстати, ты среду с правами админа запускаешь?

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло: удалить все DCU, выполнить CLEAN проекта.

(см. https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108031)